# Is it safe to insert into an unordered_multimap while iterating over elements with the same key?

Tags: c++11, g++, clang

I'm experiencing a different behavior with this code on different platforms and different compilers (clang and g++). For g++ on Linux there seems to be no problem with this code. The inner loop is left after two iterations. But with clang on Mac OS the inner loop doesn't seem to find `range.second` and the code does not terminate.

Since there is an insertion into an std::unordered_multimap during iteration, my question is if this could cause an undesired behavior.

```
typedef pair< vector<int>, vector<int> > VPair;
typedef pair< vector<int>, VPair > V_VPair;
typedef unordered_multimap < vector<int>, VPair, VHash > V2VPairMap;

V2VPairMap v2vPairs;
//... fill v2vPairs
for(vector<int> myVector : vectorOfIntVectors) {
    //search this int vector in unordered map
    auto range = v2vPairs.equal_range(myVector);
    for (auto it = range.first; it != range.second; ++it)
    {
        pair< vector<int>, vector<int> > aPair = it->second;
        //...
        V_VPair newPair1(newVector1, aPair);
        V_VPair newPair2(newVector2, aPair);
        v2vPairs.insert(newPair1); // <----- safe?
        v2vPairs.insert(newPair2); // <----- safe?
    }
    v2vPairs.erase(myVector); // <-- should be safe
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [std::unordered_multimap::insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap/insert):

> If rehashing occurs due to the insertion, all iterators are invalidated. Otherwise iterators are not affected. References are not invalidated.

In other words, that insertion may invalidate your existing iterators and cause undefined behaviour.

Comment: than I should insert after the loop, probably. Is there a reason why this happens with clang and not with g++? Or is it pure coincidence?

Comment: @Sadik Different implementation of hash tables, so they probably rehash at different times.